# Long Figure Wrap

Tags: wrap

May I ask how to auto-wrap a too-long figure as shown below(sleepy channel protocol), so that the overflow part of the figure can be shown in the next page automatically?  Thanks.

Note: The paper is already in double-column format.

[image: long Figure]

This figure is from:https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1445.pdf, page 17

Comment: Hope you expecting `multicols` and the usage is `\usepackage{multicol}` and `\begin{multicols}{2}`...`\end{multicols}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks for your advice. But the paper is already in double-column format. So multicols command may not work

Comment: You can use multicols inside a figure*, however you cannot have a float of any sort longer than one page.  You have to manually split it, or use `\captionof{figure}{...}`.